# ip addressed not responding : but 127.0.0.1 responding : Apache

Tags: apache, xampp

I currently have Apache running as part of XAMPP and I am able to run the PHP scripts by accessing them at `127.0.0.1/<program_name>.php` but when I try to access them as `<my_ip>/<program_name>.php` I get no response.

Am I doing something incorrectly or does my configuration need fixing?

Comment: You could also edit your etc/hosts to point 172.x.x.x to localhost for development/debugging purposes. The original post needs a lot more information for help to be provided. Please add more detail and apache config and OS details.

Comment: MY OS is Windows 7, httpd-conf only LISTENing to port 80.
Any suggested changes to httpd.conf (from answers related to my problem) to correct the situation is leading to crashing of Apache!!

Answer (score 0):

assuming you are trying to access from an external ip address you need to setup your router (port forwarding) to send web traffic to the LAN ip of your machine.

you also may need to disable various firewalls at various points in your network.

In short there is not enough information given to provide you a definitive answer.